# Why is the Biblical Second Temple Pesach not mentioned in Seder Korban Pesach?

Tags: tefilla, passover, torah-study, korban-pesach

Some have the custom to recite Seder Korban Pesach (a description of the Korban Pesach service in the Temple) on the afternoon of Erev Pesach. Some include before this recitation a selection of biblical passages dealing with the Korban Pesach. See eg [here](http://www.ttidbits.com/1038/1038sakp.pdf).

However, there is a conspicuous absence from this list of references: The Pesach celebrated by the returnees at the start of the Second Temple Era, described in [Ezra 6:19-22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.6.19?lang=bi).

Why is this account not included?

Comment: There are various versions of this recitation. Are you sure none include it?

Comment: All the ones I’ve seen don’t include it - but there could very well be ones that I’ve not seen that do include it. A reference to one of those would be great. Either way, the question stands for the versions without it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, my [Oz V'hadar Mesivta Haggadah, extended edition,](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/63/pesach) does indeed include it in brackets (p. 57).

In their discussion of the Minhag (p. 309) they reference the Ma'aseh Rav (§190), which lists the passages which the Gra would say. As you note, he leaves out the passage from Ezra. They pose this question (ad. loc., ft. 4) in the name of several Achronim (R' Moshe Shapira quoting the Ohr Sameiach; the Aderet). They quote two answers (it's unclear from their wording who said which answer):

1. The Gra doesn't hold that one should say Pesukim regarding the Karban Pesach in the Second Temple, since the Temple didn't have the same level of holiness as the First one (cf. Yoma 21b and 52b).
2. Those Karbanos which Ezra brought were from animals taken from Daryavesh and his advisers; this was a Hora'as Sha'ah, since in general one may not buy animals from an idolater (cf. Avodah Zarah 22a). Since the purpose of saying Seder Karban Pesach is that our speech should substitute for actually bringing the Karbanos, we prefer to only discuss Karbanos brought in the ideal manner.

Comment: Thanks! Great find. Out of interest, does your Oz VeHadar version include any other passages in brackets?

Comment: Not in Amiras Karban Pesach, anyway. There’s a few sections throughout the Haggadah, most notably throughout Nishmas, where they do this.